# Why do I get different results in git bash (msysgit) and git in cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

I alyways used the git bash but now I have to change to cygwin because I need wget and other things, so I thought I could use the builtin git as well since it is newer.

The git bash is version 1.9.4-preview, the one in cygwin is version 2.1.4. I have a cloned repo I worked with using the git bash. I commited and pushed everything and I'm on the develop branch. When I use "git status" I get this:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

In cygwin I get this part

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
```

But then I get a list of hundreds of files that are not staged for commit. Why do I get different results? I'm in the same directory in the same repo, the results should be the same.

Comment: I don't know the details, but this sounds like a line-ending problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s most likely due to differences between the two Git configurations.  Git
uses a number of configuration settings to tell it how to behave such as how
to treat differences between DOS and Unix-style line endings. These include:

- `core.autocrlf`
- `core.ignorecase`
- `core.eol`

See `git config --help` for more info on these and other configuration options.

You should run the following commands on both systems and compare the configuration settings:

- `git config --system --list`
- `git config --global --list`

Note that the global settings take precedence over the system settings. The *system* settings are set for every user on the system (`/etc/gitconfig` in Cygwin) while the *global* settings are for only your user account (`~/.gitconfig` on Cygwin) and apply to all your repositories.

Also: you can also run `git config --local --list` to see the configuration
settings which are local to the repository – but these will be the same on
both Cygwin and MSys Git.

Comment: Thanks that was it. For future reference: The cygwin git config is under (c:)/cygdrive/home/USERNAME, the windows git config was under (c:)/users/USERNAME

Comment: Check also the "core.filemode" option. The value 'false' may help.